# Optimal top-k column subset

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization

Let $V$ be a set of vectors over $\mathbb{R}^l$, $l\ge 1$, $\pi_i(V)$ be the permutation of vectors in $V$ such that they are ordered by their $i$th component (descending) in order for $\pi_i(V)(\mathbf{v})$ to be the rank of $\textbf{v}$ by component $I$: then define
$$
\operatorname{top}(V, k) := \sum_{i=0}^l \sum_{\substack{\mathbf{v} \\ \pi_i(V)(\textbf{v}) < k}} \mathbf{v}_i
$$
What we desire is an algorithm (ideally involving polynomial time/space complexity in $|V|$) such that for a given $n$, $k \ll |V|$, we can find the subset of vectors $V^* \subset V, |V^*| = n$ that maximizes $\operatorname{top}(V^*, k)$.

Intuitively we can think of our set as a matrix (though it's column order invariant), and we can think of the $\operatorname{top}$ function as "sparsifying" any sub-matrix, by setting all but the top $k$ values in each row of that sub-matrix to 0. Then our goal is to select the $n$ columns that maximize the sum total of values in the sparsified sub-matrix.

I've played around a little bit with reductions to NP-Hard problems, but don't see anything obvious. You can easily compute the effect of "swapping" one vector for another in our selected subset, but it's not obvious to me that the greedy algorithm this implies would produce an optimal solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is an order of $l$, compared with $n$, $k$, and $|V|$?

Comment: Our practical values are; $10^5 < |V| < 10^7$, $n \approx 100$, $k < 10$...
$l$ is a bit more tricky. $l$ actually represents samples from a "dataset distribution", so we should expect that as $l$ grows, $V^*$ converges to some stable set. It's hard to know when this will happen, and it will likely depend on $|V|$ and $|k|$, but my guess would be $O(1000s)$

Comment: But what is $s$?

Comment: Sorry that was just thousands. An interesting consequence of this actually, is that an algorithm that is online for components is highly preferable (as it would prevent us from needing to choose a value for $l$, we could instead make some choices around convergence [i.e. we've added 10 new dimensions and $V^*$ has remained stable)